# Import file to mysql database resulting in bad accents

Tags: php, mysql

I have a utf8 json file containing some stuff like that :

```
"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-73.6371999890417,45.451049968774],[-73.6362864025022,45.4507004803266]]},"properties":{"FIN_GCH":191,"TYP_VOIE":"avenue","LIM_GCH":"Montréal-Ouest","NOM_VOIE":"Brock","CLASSE":0,"DEB_DRT":0,"FIN_DRT":0,"LIM_DRT":"Montréal-Ouest","LIE_VOIE":"","DEB_GCH":173,"ID_TRC":1602102,"DIR_VOIE":"Sud","SENS_CIR":-1}}
,{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[-73.6382813452807,45.4514760942107],[-73.6371999890417,45.451049968774]]},"properties":{"FIN_GCH":171,"TYP_VOIE":"avenue","LIM_GCH":"Montréal-Ouest","NOM_VOIE":"Brock","CLASSE":0,"DEB_DRT":150,"FIN_DRT":152,"LIM_DRT":"Montréal-Ouest","LIE_VOIE":"","DEB_GCH":143,"ID_TRC":1602103,"DIR_VOIE":"Sud","SENS_CIR":-1}}
```

With the help of a php script, i put all the data in a mysql UTF8 database but even so, the entries have weird accents : instead of Montréal-Ouest i have MontrÃ©al-Ouest

Do you have any idea what is the problem please ?

Thank you

Comment: You probably did not specify the character encoding to be used for the database connection in your script.

Comment: I use PDO. That could be, i'll try it now

Comment: Haha you were right, thank you. I found how by searching

Answer (score 0):

I had to set a utf8 connection with the server by setting the options array like this

```
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND    => "SET NAMES utf8"
  );

$connection = new PDO( $dns, $user, $password, $options );
```

Thanks to CBroe